# Parallel execution of multiple optimization process with JAXOpt

Tags: python, machine-learning, mathematical-optimization, jax

I'm using JaxOpt (an optimization framework written for JAX) for a master degree thesis on parameter estimation of dynamical systems in system biology.

**Goal**: Multiple optimization of the same model with different initial solutions.

I have tried two different things:

1. VMAP on the objective function and run a single optimization
2. VMAP the `solver.run` method.

The first approach does not work at all. This because, since the solution is not a vector anymore, instead it is a matrix of point, the `condition` function of the inner while loop raise a JAX error of the type: `cond_fun must return a boolean scalar, but got output type(s) [ShapedArray(bool[3])].`. Indeed, I would like not to change the source code, hence this is not the rigth approach I guess.

On the second approach, I decided to VMAP the entire optimization. The problem is that, it tooks a lot of time to complete, since there is no real parallelization happening here. Obviously, you have to assume that the simulation and computation of the gradient are expensive and each optimization step takes some time to complete.

How can I proceed?

Here is the code to reproduce the error with the first approach:

```
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp
import jaxopt

@jax.jit
@jax.value_and_grad
def loss(params, x, target) -> jnp.ndarray:
    """ Compute the loss function """
    diff = params * x - target
    return diff.T @ diff / diff.shape[0]

# Define the initial starting points
params = jnp.array(np.random.uniform(size=(3, 10)))
x = jnp.array(np.random.uniform(size=(10,)))
x = jnp.tile(x, (3,1))
target = jnp.array(np.random.uniform(size=(10,))) * 10
target = jnp.tile(target, (3,1))

# VMAP on the loss function
_loss = jax.vmap(loss)

solver = jaxopt.GradientDescent(_loss, maxiter=100, value_and_grad=True)
params, res = solver.run(params, x, target)
```

Comment: Can you share more about what hardware you're using? Are you on CPU or GPU? Do you have multiple devices available, or are you hoping for some kind of single-device thread parallelism?

Comment: Yeah, for sure. I'm using JAX with CUDA on a single NVIDIA GPU. I have already opened an issue on the github page of JaxOpt. However, I didn't receive any response yet.

Comment: If you're running on a single GPU, I wouldn't expect to gain much by running models in parallel. A single model run should already make good use of the available GPU flops. If you have multiple devices available, you may be able to do better